# How to manipulate a data?

Tags: r

I'm confused with an exercise that i'm working on in R. I'm just a beginner in R

the instructions is to Use `dplyr` to manipulate the data so that you have the **proportion immunised** (i.e. Immunised divided by Eligible) for each `DHB`, for each `Age`, and each `Date`. Save the result so you can use it for the remaining questions. *You should end up with a data frame containing variables for `DHB`, `Date`, `Age` and `Proportion` with 4834 observations.*

But I don't understand how to do this but this is what i've tried

````
```{r}
vacc %>% mutate(Proportion = Immunised/DHB(vacc))

vacc %>% select(DHB, Date, Age, Proportion)
```
````

but it gave me this error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Proportion`. x could not find function "DHB" i Input `Proportion` is `Immunised/DHB(vacc)`.
```

can someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DHB` is a column in the dataframe, however, you are using it as function.

You can `group_by` `DHB`, `Age` and `Date` and calculate ratio between `Immunised` and `Eligible`.

```
library(dplyr)
vacc %>%  group_by(DHB, Age, Date) %>% mutate(Proportion = Immunised/Eligible)
```

Perhaps, I think this would work too :

```
vacc %>%  mutate(Proportion = Immunised/Eligible)
```